# qemu external snapshot

Tags: qemu

qemu-kvm-1.5.3-141.el7_4.4.x86_64

Не получается создать снепшот:

```
virsh snapshot-create-as --domain vm1 snapshot --disk-only --atomic --quiesce --no-metadata
```

Ошибка:

```
error: Операция не поддерживается: Этот QEMU не поддерживает создание снимка работающего диска
```

В госте установлен и работает qemu-ga.

Comment: т.е. без ключа --disk-only работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.
Обновил qemu-kvm до 2.9 из репозиториев Овирт.